# splash sound fluctuates or breaks

Tags: android

i have added one 5 second sound mp3 to my app on splash screen, but its playing fluctuates while loading of app, what do i need to do for smooth playing??

```
public class Splash extends Activity{
    MediaPlayer ourSong;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle TravisLoveBacon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(TravisLoveBacon);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.onkar);
        ourSong.start();
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(4000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.sport.sport.MAINLAUNCHER2");
                    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        ourSong.release();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you need to do for smooth playing? More CPU, especially in the UI-Thread. (ok, just kidding :-)

You can use `SoundPool` and pre-load the song before you play it. SoundPool is especially made for short sounds within games or the like.

Here's the shortest piece of code to load an play some music. Remember to run it in an `AsyncTask`. It might take half a second to start but it runs then without problem.

```
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
        if(status == 0) soundPool.play(sampleId, 1f, 1f, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0, 1f);
    }
});
try {
    soundId = soundPool.load(getAssets().openFd(file), 1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage(), e);
    return;
}
```

It needs at least API level 8 and uses the volume for music.

Two other things I see in your code:

- No matter if it's SoundPool or media player. You should run the sound playing part in background.
- How did you do it to `startActivity` in another thread??? That part should not work.

Comment: its a splash main activity, when application starts its dispalyed first

Comment: could you please adapt my code with sound pool, i m new to this

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would build a Splash screen with some sound on it.

It's getting quite long, so let me make some remarks about it.

- Because it's so long I've put it into a new answer
- As loading and playing sounds is still asynchronous, there's a chance, that your Splash screen will just flash and the next Activity will be started immediately. In this case, you must use a Java-Lock, like a `Semaphore` that you set and `aquire` in `doInBackground` and that you `release()` at the end of `onLoadComplete()`.

That's it. Haven't tested it heavily but hope you can use it starting point:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    /*
     * I would finish here, to give
     * Android some time for layout
     * and other things
     */
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onResume()
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    /*
     * Now start background task
     * There was a discussion about
     * Splash screen some time ago.
     * Especially when you should do the
     * startActivity and what flags you
     * should use in the Intent.
     */

    // Start playing sound asynchronously
    // R.raw.onkar
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        private SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(
                1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Put in here the code I've already posted!
            return null;
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            soundPool.release();

            Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(
                    "com.sport.sport.MAINLAUNCHER2");
            startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            /*
             * Actually, you can start the next activity here
             * or from onResume method with postDelayed(...)
             * This way here ensures that the Activity is
             * started right after the sound was played.
             */
        }
    }.execute((Void) null);
}
}
```